# In a grid change the Selected Item Model properties but it should not reflect back in the grid unless user saves it

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am working on a wpf application, where most of the screens consist of a details grid and a form where the selected item of the grid is displayed.

In this details form the user can update the individual properties of the selected item.

This is a MVVM application and in my view model i have exposed two properties one is observable collection of the model which acts as item source for the grid. and there is a Selected Item Model which binds to the selected item of the grid.

Now my problem is when user changes any property of the selected item in the details forms, it automatically reflects back to the grid, i have tried changing modes of binding but nothing works.

I just want to make sure the selected item changes but it should not be reflected back to grid unless user saves these changes.

Comment: why are you using a special property to store the selected value? since this is an mvvm application the proper way to do this would be to use a command when the grid selected item changes (like a DelegateCommand if you are using Prism or something identical in a different mvvm framework) and there, send the selected item as a parameter. this way the selected item is not binded and you can update programatically when the users saves the changes ...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a designated property in your view model for the selected item, in your xaml that displays the grid you can use something like this:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3" 
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
    xmlns:ie="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow" 
    x:Name="MyMainWindow">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="myGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding myItems}">
        <ie:Interaction.Triggers>
            <ie:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <ie:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedItemChangedCommand}"  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myGrid, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
            </ie:EventTrigger>
        </ie:Interaction.Triggers>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Then in your View Model :

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        myItems = new ObservableCollection<Person>
        {
            new Person("John", 23),
            new Person("Kobi", 25),
            new Person("Lizard", 43)
        };

        SelectedItemChangedCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>((selectedItem) => 
            {
                var selected = selectedItem as Person;

                // Do whatever you want to display the properties of your selected item
                // and let you user change them
            });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Person> myItems { get; set; }

    public DelegateCommand<object> SelectedItemChangedCommand { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public Person(string name, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Note that in this example I used Prism library but you can do the same with other mvvm libraries too.

Comment: Hi Ombribitan, I have already tried this, it does not work since we are copying the reference of the selected item (var selected = selectedItem as Person;), so any change reflects back to the grid.

Comment: @Saurabh then don't copy the reference. Use a copy constructor or some other cloning technique to create a duplicate of the selected instance. then when the user hits save update the real selected item..

Answer (score 0):

`UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit` might be what you are after..

From MSDN:

> When you set the UpdateSourceTrigger value to Explicit, the source value only changes when the application calls the UpdateSource method

Then in your save method just call `UpdateSource` method.
Example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpression.updatesource.aspx)

From the example MSDN:

> If you have a dialog or a user-editable form and you want to defer source updates until the user is finished editing the fields and clicks "OK", you can set the UpdateSourceTrigger value of your bindings to Explicit

Comment: @Saurabh Regardless, I still don't think its a good idea to have a designated property for the selected item..